# How does a sender app resume the session after being killed?

Tags: google-cast

The User Experience guidelines state that the sender app should resume the session after it is killed and restarted. Specifically it says "If the sender app gets killed, it should have the Cast session context stored and be able to resume the session from that context when the sender app is restarted." Few questions...

1. What does "Cast session context" mean in this situation? Is this some object or objects in the Cast API that can be persisted then restored OR or something more general?
2. In order for this to happen and not interfere with another app that may have cast to the same device while the original app was dead, the new instance of the original app must be able to query if a given device is running the original app's receiver, some other receiver or no receiver. How is this accomplished?
3. If the app is to resume to the same Chromecast device then some identifier for the device must be saved as the app is being destroyed. Is the getDeviceId in CastDevice the correct thing to store?

Comment: Chrome senders can't currently, but iOS & Android can -- which are you asking about?

Comment: StackOverflow is designed around the concept of "one question per post". You've asked at least 5 (3 in item 1, and one each in the other 2 items), and possibly 6 if you count the title question. This is far too broad in scope; it should be broken out into multiple posts. If you want to refer to this one for some context from the additional questions, you can do so.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I'll consider that when posting in the future.

Comment: Hi Les...will this be answered or do I have to deconstruct it into 6 questions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The preview SDK has some shortcomings that prevent you from a complete implementation of this feature. When the official SDK becomes available, this will be fully addressed.

FYI, in order to reconnect your previous "state", you need to persist certain information so next time you can identify the device/route and the session that you had initiated before. Unfortunately, as I mentioned above, the APIs that you would need for a full and clean recovery process are not completely there in the preview SDK, so you can ignore this aspect of the UX Guideline till the official release provides all the needed pieces for you.